# How do I continuesly invoke a function while $().animate is animating?

Tags: jquery

I a am using the JQuery [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method to animate the growth of a `div`, while the animation is playing/animating, I want to make a function call every x amount of milliseconds until the animation is complete.

The `progress` option seems like it may do the job but it only executes once and not in intervals, havn't yet tried multiple `progress` options, but I don't want to go down that route, as I may have an animation that runs for 10s and a function to be called every 100ms.

Comment: What do you mean by 'make a call'? If you're talking about make an AJAX request every X miliseconds, that's a really bad idea which will flood your server.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry missed the word 'function' before call

Comment: Ah, that's ok then. I added an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you could use the `step` property of the `options` object. However note that it executes once *per iteration* of the animation. This is not guaranteed to be a set number of ms between calls as it depends on a lot of factors, such as how fast the animation is, how quick the client PC can render the changes etc. Here's a working example:

```js
$('.foo').animate({
  left: 300
},{
  duration: 3000,
  step: function() {
    console.log($(this).css('left'))
  }
});
```

```css
.foo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">Foo</div>
```

Alternatively you can start an interval timer when the animation starts and clear it when the animation ends, like this:

```js
var $foo = $('.foo');

$('button').click(function() {
  var interval = setInterval(update, 100);
  $foo.animate({
    left: 300
  }, 3000, function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  });
});

function update() {
  console.log($foo.css('left'));
}
```

```css
.foo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">Foo</div>

<button>Start</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, seems neat, but it does not allow me to specify how often it makes a call :(

Comment: Yes, the second method does that. At the moment it's set to make the call every 100ms. I'd be wary of doing anything faster than that in JS as you may make the animation less smooth.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `clearInterval()`

```
<button>Button</button>
<div style = "background-color :black; height:100px; width: 100px; ">Div</div>



$("button").click(function(){
    var myVar = setInterval(function() {
        console.log("Happening...");
        // whatever you want to do here
    },100);
    $("div").animate({
            opacity: 0,
        }, 5000, function() {
            clearInterval(myVar);
        }
    );
}); 
</script>
```